# Unable to remove redirected printer

Tags: windows, permissions, printer, windows-home-server

I don't know what these redirected devices are on my Windows Home Server. One is a printer which I can't print to and the other a fax (which I don't have).

The shared printer in the picture is connected locally and works fine, so I tried removing the redirected one but got the error `Access is denied, unable to remove device`. I get the same error for the fax.

[image: Remove Device: Access is denied, unable to remove device]

I've tried taking ownership of the objects from `SYSTEM` using the **Advanced Security Settings** dialog, but that didn't help.

It's just a little housekeeping, and not an issue, but how can I remove them?

Comment: Don't know if this will help but give it a read and see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/08/24/terminal-server-and-printer-redirection.aspx

Comment: I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I have the same issue. I have had this issue for a while and have not found anything that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is mapping your printer on your local machine through your RDP session, if that is how you are accessing the server.

You can edit the RDP shortcut by clicking the "Local Resources" tab and unchecking the printers check box.

This will stop your local printer from being redirected. In this case your local printer appears to be the same as the one being shared, which might explain the trouble printing to its redirected version.

[image]

Comment: Took three answers, and a few years, but thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1):

you can also disable remote printing all together in settings for RDP client before you connect. You can also use RDP client on MAC to print locally from a MAC over RDP client .. I know right its crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Unticking the printers checkbox in the RDP comnection settings will stop the redirection when you use RDP to remote in to your server.

Comment: Please explain **where** to "Unticking the printers checkbox" to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the redirected printers in Windows 10, go to Device Manager and scroll down to Print queues.  You'll see the redirected printers there.  Right click on each and click on uninstall.